# form file post to web service method not working

Tags: web-services, asmx

I am trying to have a HTML form post a file to a Asp .Net Web service method. Everything seems to work but there is no form or files on the request object in the web method. any ideas?

Html Form

```
<form id="formPost" action="service/Post" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Post File <input id="uploadfile"    type=file />
    <input type=submit value="Post" />
</form>
```

Web service

```
[WebMethod]
    public void Post()
    {        
        // file collection of uploaded files in the http context
        HttpFileCollection Files = this.Context.Request.Files;

        // always 0 and no form either
        if (Files.Count > 0)
        {}
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot post to a SOAP web service method using html form. When you submit the form data is encoded using `multipart/form-data` while a web service expects a SOAP envelope and `text/xml` content type. In order to invoke the web service you will need to generate a proxy class from the WSDL and use this proxy class to call the desired method.

Comment: Any chance of a link to some examples?

Comment: There are [many](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=asp.net+web+service+tutorial+consuming&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=9f2370386c77b788). Here's one [tutorial](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/net-web-services-5-steps). Also notice that ASMX web services are now considered deprecated technology and are replaced by WCF.

Comment: I ended up using a http handler as a better solution. Also, the file upload form element doesn't work without a name attribute. weird...

Comment: I don't totally understand this answer. There's not anything mentioned in the question about the service being a SOAP service. To me it could be a "regular" webservice..